# MongoDb Update multiple documents with different values using Spring Data mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Using spring data mongo driver, I want to update multiple documents in mongodb using one single query and these documents will have a different updated value.
I tried the following code but it would have the same updated value for all the documents that match the query criteria.

```
List<Criteria> bigCriteria = new ArrayList<Criteria>();

for (MyClass myClass : myClasses){
            Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("_id").is(myClass.getId());
            bigCriteria.add(criteria);
}

//next line is just a psedudo code to explain what I intend to do here
query = <<create an or query using bigCriteria created above>>;

Update update = new Update();
update.set("age":11);

mongoOperation.updateMulti(query, update, User.class);
```

Is there a way to update all the documents with different values ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Bulk Write api to send batches of document to server with different query criteria and update document.

Something like

```
int count = 0;
int batch = 100;
BulkOperations bulkOps = mongoOperation.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED, User.class);
for (MyClass myClass : myClasses){
    Query query = new Query();
    Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("_id").is(myClass.getId());
    query.addCriteria(criteria);
    Update update = new Update();
    update.set("age", myClass.getAge());
    bulkOps.updateOne(query, update);
    count++;
    if (count == batch) {
        bulkOps.execute();
        count = 0;
    }
}
if (count > 0) {
    bulkOps.execute();
}
```

Comment: Does your code issue all the queries at once during execute ? I don't want to issue multiple queries to mongodb

Comment: It is not possible to do it in one query but you can batch them as I have shown for efficient updates. It issues 100 queries at once.

Comment: Np. You can use `BulkOperations bulkOps = mongoOperation.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED, collectionname);`

Comment: Thanks for your help. figured the collectionsName part, so deleted that comment. Is there a limit on the batch size ? any permissible limits or recommended values ?

Comment: Np. I'll test out with different limits and see which one is optimal. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053197/what-is-the-optimum-bulk-item-count-with-insertbatch-method-in-mongodb-c-sharp-d)